# Package pgf Error: No shape named is known in tikz-cd commutative diagramm

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

There are 3 unexpected errors in my `tikz-cd` commutative diagram, called:

`Package pgf Error: No shape named A is known. I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 2-2.`

How to solve the problem with these errors?

The figure is quite good, however if we can somehow to make an arrow `xi` with length like `nu`, it would be perfect.

A MWE is here:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\begin{center} %8ex
    %       \resizebox{0.25\linewidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep = 40pt, column sep = 40pt, ampersand replacement=\&]
        \& K \& \& \& \\ 
        G \arrow[end anchor={[xshift=-1ex]}]{ur}{\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{$\varepsilon$}}}   \arrow[end anchor={[xshift=-1ex]},swap]{dr}{\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{$\delta$}}}\&     
         \arrow[from=A,start anchor={[xshift=-8ex]},end anchor={[xshift=-5ex]}]{r}{\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{$\zeta$}}}
        \& E_m \arrow{r}{\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{$\mu$}}}\& E_\leq \arrow{r}{\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{$\nu$}}} \& \mathcal{A}_\leq\\    
        \& D   
        \arrow[swap, xshift=-1.5ex,dashrightarrow,near end]{uu}{\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{$\alpha_1$}}}
        [midway]{\ldots}
        [near start]{\mbox{\scalebox{1.5}{$\alpha_q$}}}  
        \arrow[swap, xshift=1.5ex,dashrightarrow]{uu}
        \arrow[uu, phantom, xshift=1.6ex,"=:\mathcal{A}"{name=A,right}, midway]
        \& \& \&  
    \end{tikzcd}
    %       }
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

A current pdf is following:

[image]

Comment: It's zeta, not xi (`ξ`). Also, you should use  `\eqqcolon` from `mathtools` rather than `=:`: the colon is not centred on the math axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier than that: just back up by the intercolumn space:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}

\[
\tikzcdset{
 every label/.style={
    /tikz/auto,
    /tikz/font=\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\textstyle},
    /tikz/inner sep=+0.5ex},
}
    %       \resizebox{0.25\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep = 40pt, column sep = 40pt, ampersand replacement=\&]
\& K \\ 
G \arrow[end anchor={[xshift=-1ex]}]{ur}{\varepsilon}
  \arrow[end anchor={[xshift=-1ex]},swap]{dr}{\delta}
\& \&[-40pt] =:\mathcal{A} \arrow{r}{\zeta} \& 
E_m \arrow{r}{\mu} \& 
E_\leq \arrow{r}{\nu} \& \mathcal{A}_\leq\\    
\& D \arrow[swap, xshift=-1.75ex,dashrightarrow,near end]{uu}{\alpha_1}
           [midway]{\ldots}
           [near start]{\alpha_q}
     \arrow[swap, xshift=1.75ex,dashrightarrow]{uu}
\end{tikzcd}%
    %       }
\]
\end{document}
```

Note how I override the choice of `\scriptstyle` for the labels. But it's better to use the default `\scripstyle`, in my opinion.

[image]